# Fill NaN values of column X with the median value of X for each categorial variable in another column Y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, median

This was very difficult to phrase. But let me show you what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
df

Y  X
a  10
a  5
a  NaN
b  12
b  13
b  NaN
c  5
c  NaN
c  5
c  6


Y: 10 non-null object
X: 7 non-null int64
```

Take category 'a' from column Y, it has the median X value (10+5/2), the other missing value for 'a' must be filled with this median value.

Similarly, for category 'b' from column Y, among the non missing values in column X, the median X values is, (12+13/2)

For category 'c' from column Y, among the non missing values in column X, the median X values is, 5 (middle most value)

**I used a very long, repetitive code as follows.**

```
    grouped = df.groupby(['Y'])[['X']]
    grouped.agg([np.median])

                X
                median
    Y
    a           7.5
    b           12.5
    c           5

    df.X = df.X.fillna(-1)

    df.loc[(df['Y'] == 'a') & (df['X'] == -1), 'X'] = 7.5
    df.loc[(df['Y'] == 'b') & (df['X'] == -1), 'X'] = 12.5
    df.loc[(df['Y'] == 'c') & (df['X'] == -1), 'X'] = 5
```

**I was told that there is not only repetition but also the use of magic numbers, which should be avoided.**

**I want to write a function that does this filling efficiently.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform`
The transform looks like

```
df.groupby('Y').X.transform('median')

0     7.5
1     7.5
2     7.5
3    12.5
4    12.5
5    12.5
6     5.0
7     5.0
8     5.0
9     5.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

And this has the same index as before.  Therefore we can easily use it to `fillna`

```
df.X.fillna(df.groupby('Y').X.transform('median'))

0    10.0
1     5.0
2     7.5
3    12.0
4    13.0
5    12.5
6     5.0
7     5.0
8     5.0
9     6.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

You can either make a new copy of the dataframe

```
df.assign(X=df.X.fillna(df.groupby('Y').X.transform('median')))

   Y     X
0  a  10.0
1  a   5.0
2  a   7.5
3  b  12.0
4  b  13.0
5  b  12.5
6  c   5.0
7  c   5.0
8  c   5.0
9  c   6.0
```

Or `fillna` values in place

```
df.X.fillna(df.groupby('Y').X.transform('median'), inplace=True)
df

   Y     X
0  a  10.0
1  a   5.0
2  a   7.5
3  b  12.0
4  b  13.0
5  b  12.5
6  c   5.0
7  c   5.0
8  c   5.0
9  c   6.0
```

Comment: That works. I get to see the output of the imputed values. I'd like to ask one more question. What if there were many other column too, I only showed you two of the 17 columns so I could simplify the question, when I run df['X'].describe(), it shows the number of values before the missing value imputation, 7 and not 10

Comment: Nevermind, I just did,  df['X'] = df.X.fillna(df.groupby('Y').X.transform('median')), and it worked. Thank you so much!